# elastic search index template creation

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am very new to elastic-search, in my node program i am using elastic-search. In that i am trying to create an `"Index Template"` but i am receiving error:

The query:

```
 client.indices.putTemplate({
       "name":"mfi1",
       "template" : "te*"
}).then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
}, function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

But i am receiving error:

```
  {
    "error": "ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesArray@1]",
    "status": 400
  }
```

Help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya i found a solution:

I reconstructed my query as following:

```
{
        name : "mfi3",
        body:{
            "template" : "te*",
            "settings" : {
                "number_of_shards" : 1
            },
            "mappings" : {
                "type1" : {
                    "_source" : { "enabled" : false }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Its working fine.

Comment: That solved it for me too, you can mark this answer as the solution.